# R dim argument specifications

Tags: dimensions

I am trying to understand what the `[2]` means when using dim.

I have read the dim function documentation but have not found anything about

```
y1 <- dataset.train[, dim(dataset.train)[2]]
```

Comment: It accesses the second item in the vector returned by the dim function. I recommend learning the basics of R to ease further development.

Comment: thank you Patrick, will definitely have a look